# How to check that an array is reciprocally equal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have an array of items that contain two variables, indexes and types, and need to group these items by exact matches of these two variables.

```
[{ types: ['a', 'b'], indexes: ['i0', 'i1']}, { types: ['c', 'd'], indexes: ['i2', 'i3']}, ...]
```

At the moment, the code creates an array containing the unique pairs of indexes and types from the items, then groups them together by iterating through and adding them to a temporary array. I believe this is done through lodash and then filtered to generate the pairs.

The problem being, it currently only checks if the item contains all of the types and indexes present in the unique pairs. So if there is a pair with types: a, b, c; it would match anything containing any combination of those three, not exactly those three.

I've added a reciprocal .every check to verify the opposite way, but I'm unsure if there's a more efficient way to do this.

The end result should be an array of items that contain only other items that exactly match both types and indexes in both directions.

**EDIT**:

So, the existing code is:

```
const distinctIndexTypes =
  _.uniqWith(
    Object.values(items).map(item => { indexes: item.indexes, types: item.types }),
    _.isEqual,
  );

const queries = [];
distinctIndexTypes.forEach(indexType => {
  const aggs = [];
  Object.values(items).forEach(item => {
    if (
      indexType.indexes.every(index => item.indexes.includes(index)) &&
      item.indexes.every(index => indexType.indexes.includes(index)) &&
      item.types.every(type => indexType.types.includes(type)) &&
      indexType.types.every(type => item.types.includes(type))
    ) {
      aggs.push(item);
    }
  });

  if (aggs.length > 0) {
    queries.push({
      aggs,
    });
  }
});
```

The aim is to get an array of queries that contain types and indexes that are exactly equal to reduce the number of queries from one per item, to one per distinct set.

Comment: So why don't you show what you tried that failed and give an example of of things that match these edge cases.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would show the solution you came up with, or at the least an example of what you want the code to do.

Comment: @BrooksLybrand Updated to include the original code and what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for adding your code. Unfortunately this code doesn't actually run. You have a `...` in your push inside the last if statement, so I'm not sure what you want to go there. Also, instead of `contains` do you mean `includes`. `contains` is not an array method.

Comment: Sorry! I did mean includes! There's a few misc elements supposed to go in with the ... but it's not important, so I'll take that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about grouping by a formatted key?

```
var groups = _.groupBy(items, item => _.sortBy(item.types) + ";" + _.sortBy(item.indexes))
var queries2 = _.map(groups, g => { return { aggs: g }; })
```